# Model inheritance with strong typing

Tags: .net, inheritance, object, model

I have a tricky modelling problem, on which I'd like to have another point of view.

I'm dealing with a model that is treated as a whole by some engines. It looks like that (names are not what we are using):

```
public class Container{
  // Some other specific properties and methods, ctor etc

  public IList<Group> Groups {get; private set;}

  // For convenience, we need that
  public IList<Element> Elements {get; private set;}
}

public class Group{
  // Specific stuff here      

  public IList<Element> Elements{get; private set;}

  public Container Container{get; set;}
}

public class Element{
  public Group Group {get; set;}
}
```

All along the model, we have those double references, because the model is treated as a whole by engines.

Now, the tricky part: I need to create 2 specific models, sharing this organization.

Currently, I have a model with three classes: Container - Group - Element.

I need to create specific models sharing the same structure, but with specific classes all along the model.

- BaseContainer, BaseGroup, BaseElement (parent)
- ContainerFoo - GroupFoo - ElementFoo (first child)
- ContainerBar - GroupBar - ElementBar (second child)

**And, to be complete, the most important thing is that I need strongly typed collections. For example, I need a list of GroupFoo in ContainerFoo, not a list of the parent type.**

I explored 2 ways of achieving this : generics and creating new properties.

For example:

```
public class BaseContainer<TGroup, TElement>{
  public IList<TGroup> Groups {get; private set;}

  public IList<TElement> Elements{get; private set;}  
}

public class BaseGroup<TContainer, TElement>{
  public TContainer Container {get; set;}

  public IList<TElement> Elements {get; private set;}
}

public class BaseElement<TGroup>{

  public TGroup Group{get; set;}

}

public class ContainerFoo: BaseContainer<GroupFoo, ElementFoo>{
  // Specific stuff here
}

public class GroupFoo: BaseGroup<ContainerFoo, ElementFoo>{
}

public class ElementFoo: BaseElement<ContainerFoo>{
}
```

This solution works in this case but:

- List of types in container can be very long, because the container is actually the entry point of the whole model (simplified here)
- We can't actually use it with protobuf-net, used for serialization and deserialization.

Second solution:

```
 public abstract class BaseContainer{

  public abstract IList<BaseGroup> Groups {get;}

  public abstract IList<BaseElement> Elements{get;}  
}

public abstract class BaseGroup{
  public abstract BaseContainer Container {get; set;}
}

public abstract class BaseElement{

  public abstract BaseGroup Group{get; set;}
}

public ContainerFoo : BaseContainer{

  public override IList<BaseGroup> Groups {
    get{
      // We are using .Net 4, and we can do that.
      return (IList<BaseGroup>)this.GroupsFoo;
    }
  }

 public IList<GroupFoo> GroupsFoo{ get; private set;}

 // Same thing for elements
}

// You see the point, I don't want to create other classes here.
```

I think you can obviously see what I don't like about this second solution!

Any more ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `abstract/override` you can use the `new` modifier on the properties of the derived classes:

```
class Container {
  public IList<Group> Groups { get; private set; }
}

class ContainerFoo : Container {
  public new IList<GroupFoo> Groups { get { return (IList<GroupFoo>)base.Groups; } }
}
```

Alternatively, is there any real benefit in using inheritence here? Would you be better off defining a generic `IContainer<T>` interface and doing away with the base class?

```
interface IContainer<TGroup> where T : Group {
  IList<TGroup> Groups { get; }
}

class ContainerFoo : IContainer<GroupFoo> {
  public IList<GroupFoo> Groups { get; private set; }
}

class ContainerBar : IContainer<GroupBar> {
  public IList<GroupBar> Groups { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The new modifier can be useful. I'll check it out. No need to create a new instance of list at every access, it seems I can cast it instead.

Comment: About interfaces, I have some common behaviors I need to implement in base class.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your common behaviours it may be possible to split them out into another class. I try to use interfaces and composition instead of inheritence where possible. If you find you need different behaviours at different times (such as a Foo and Bar use behaviour A while Baz uses behaviour B) you can make use of a strategy rather than an increasingly complex inheritence hiearchy.

Comment: Yeah, we are using strategies too, but in different places. This time, we need some utilitary functions used to manage the model, other properties, managed with rules etc. We also have some methods called on deserialization I'd like not to copy across different classes.